# Mailman, Gmail, Google Group inter-import

Tags: gmail, google-groups

Anyone knows a method to import Google Groups/Mailman archives into Gmail?

I really need to use the search function inside Gmail.

Answer (score 3):

I'm years late, but I believe you can:

- Export mbox files from mailman.
- Import them into Thunderbird
- Use an IMAP connection to move the messages from your local Thunderbird set up to your gmail account.

And then you'll be able to search like a pro.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming your Mailman archives are available (see http://wiki.list.org/display/DOC/How+do+I+make+the+archives+searchable), then you should be able to download a copy to your local machine.  From there, it's a matter of figuring out how you can import those archives into Gmail.

Note that you will probably want the private full archives of the list, in true "mbox" format.  Otherwise, you'll have to process the archives you download into a format that can be properly imported (see http://wiki.list.org/display/DOC/Processing+old+mbox+archives+with+procmail-formail).

Comment: Do you actually have a method of importing the archive into Gmail, like the OP asked?